Are there notable contemporary scientists and physicists who are mathematical Platonists?
This question is motivated by @TKoL's answer to Under physicalism, what is the ontological status of the laws of logic, and what is their relationship to the laws of physics?. He said:

Physicalism - and I'm sure what I'm about to say is going to be seen
as self-contradictory to some people - doesn't actually have to be the
claim that literally everything is physical. A physicalist could take
a layered view of reality.
Maybe the base layer is logic and mathematical facts.
The next layer up is the entire multiverse that can be created from
those facts.
Then this universe.
Then everything in this universe.
Physicalism CAN just be the statement that that last category -
everything in this universe - is physical, BUT that what it means to
"Be Physical" rests on a bedrock of non-physical concepts.

I asked for the name of this view and further clarification in the comments, to which he replied:

I don't belieive it has a separate name - as someone who holds this view, I'm pretty sure most of us just call ourselves 'physicalists', and I kind of want to wager that a sizable fraction of people who call thmselves physicalists believe something like that - sizeable as in, maybe greater than 30%, possibly even greater than 50%
If I had to name it, I might call it "nuanced physicalism" or "Mathematical Platonism + Physicalism" or "Emergentist Physicalism".
This probably isn't worth much, but ChatGPT says: "Physicalists Who Accept Mathematical Truths as Independent (Platonist Leaning Physicalists): This view is common among scientifically-minded physicalists who see mathematics as indispensable for understanding the natural world but are less concerned with reconciling its existence with physicalism strictly.... Scientific Physicalists: Many physicalists working in scientific fields lean towards views that treat mathematics as indispensable for describing physical laws but are agnostic about whether it has an independent existence."

Are there notable scientists and, in particular, theoretical physicists who defend mathematical Platonism, and if so, what solutions have they proposed to the causal interaction problem between the Platonic and the physical?

What do I mean by "causal interaction problem between the Platonic and the physical"?
I see at least two areas where some form of causal interaction arguably should exist between the Platonic realm and the physical:

The applicability of Platonic mathematical truths in physics: This is evident in the fact that physical laws can be expressed mathematically. How is this applicability explained? Did the Platonic realm somehow cause the physical realm to adhere to Platonic principles? Or is this merely a coincidence?

The epistemic accessibility of Platonic truths: Human brains, which are biological and thus physical systems, are capable of contemplating and discussing Platonic truths. This suggests there must be some kind of causal chain connecting the Platonic realm to physical brains. How does this causal chain operate?


I would like to know a summary of what notable contemporary Platonist scientists or physicists have said on either of these two points.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Small p platonism, the idea that abstract objects exist independently from the minds of humans, is held by about half of philosophers https://survey2020.philpeople.org/survey/results/4818.  That one instance of abstraction realism, that of moral realism, is held by nearly 2/3 of philosophers is an illustration of the internal conflicts that thinking through abstraction reality tend to lead to:  https://survey2020.philpeople.org/survey/results/4866
The SEP article on abstract objects asserts that they are by definition acausal.  This is silly, as if they were acausal, then we could not think about and mentally interact with them.  And as causation itself is an abstraction (it is a logic relation), as is the state sequencing feature of time, these particular abstractions are by definition CAUSAL, so the assertion of a-causality as a general feature of abstractions is readily testable and refuted by test.
If philosopher are conflicted and confused about abstract objects, one should expect physicists to be even more conflicted, and have even less internal consistency in their views.
I have seen multiple theoretical physicists treat abstractions as intrinsic to physics.
TKol in the OP question is among the most explicit I have seen, with his assertion of our universe being fundamentally abstract/idealist, with matter/physics being emergent from ideas.   I agree that several top level features of his view -- embrace of strong emergence, plus abstract/material dualism -- are pretty widely held among physicalists today. That logic or abstractions are more fundamental phan physics -- I have not seen that assertion held quite as often.  And RECOGNITION that one is an abstract/matter dualist and hold by strong emergence -- that is something that I have not seen as explicitly realized even by many who intrinsically hold that view.  That both an interactive dualist worldview, and strong emergence break the causal closure of matter -- is similarly not something that I have seen many fully grapple with.
OK, examples of others who accept the fundamentality of abstractions:
Max Tegmark is the best known of the "math creates everything" approach to theoretical physics.  TKol's answer elaborated on Tegmark's thinking, and how at least portions of it are widely held.
Sean Carroll argues that the Many Worlds interpretation of QM is the correct one, "because the other worlds are in the math".  IE this is a purely math/abstraction rationale for the reality an infinity of other universes, without any actual evidence.  This is to hold that abstractions generate worlds.
The informational and relational interpretations of QM treat QM as generated by an abstraction.
All the Copenhagen advocates who say "shut up and calculate" are implicitly arguing that math is identical to reality.
M-theory string theorists, who reject empirical testing to validate a physics claim, are adopting a platonic "the math is satisfying" criteria for reality.  See https://fau.digital.flvc.org/islandora/object/fau%3A1355/datastream/OBJ/view/Transcendental_minds_and_mythical_strings__the_emergence_of_platonism_in_modern_physics_.pdf
Additionally, basically all physicists cannot DO physics without information and relationships as well as matter presumed and specified.  The Holographic principle illustrates this.
So -- I consider that all physicists, while practicing physics, are matter/abstraction interactive dualists.  But that most today do not recognize this.  And HOW abstractions and matter interact -- is not well understood by basically anyone, either physicists or philosophers.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Max Tegmark, while perhaps not explicitly "a Platonist", is someone who apparently believes in some kind of deep mathematical reality that underpins our physical universe. I'm not informed well enough to give you the full run-down on his beliefs in this area, but he has a book called Our Mathematical Universe.
Wikipedia has something interesting to say:

The culmination that Tegmark seeks to lead us to is the "Level IV
multiverse". This level contends that the Universe is not just well
described by mathematics, but, in fact, is mathematics. All possible
mathematical structures have a physical existence, and collectively,
give a multiverse that subsumes all others. Here, Tegmark is taking us
well beyond accepted viewpoints, advocating his personal vision for
explaining the Universe.

I don't think that all of his views combined all together are necessarily extremely popular among similar experts, but bits and pieces of his beliefs here are (subjectively, according to me, and I'm not qualified to have a very strong opinion aout this) probably not especially rare.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_universe_hypothesis -> "Tegmark extends this idea to hypothesize that all mathematical objects exist, which he describes as a form of Platonism or Modal realism."

@JD should I change it to "explicitly a platonist" then?
